# Chat layout with BoxLayout manager

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

Box layout seems to be quite suitable for the needs of typical chat layout like the one I've made in InkScape.
[image]

I have based the structure like this:

```
MainFrame
  Chat JPanel - BoxLayout.Y_AXIS
    Message list - ScrollablePanel
       the list - BoxLayout.Y_AXIS
    Text field - Just a text field
```

Now the only problem I seem to have is, that in the inital phase, the space is divided 50% to 50% between text field and the message list.

[image]

However, if the message area is filled, as you can see in the image above and I try to resize the chat window, everything goes well:

[image]

So:

1. I want the textarea to keep the same size, even when message container is empty.
2. There must be a method to be called to simulate me resizing the window so that the panels update properly.

Here is the chat panel:

```
public class ChatPanel extends JPanel {
    private BoxLayout layout;
    private TextField input;
    private MessageList messages;
    public ChatPanel() {
      layout = new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
      setLayout(layout);
      //Create message list
      messages = new MessageList();
      messages.appendTo(this);
      //Create text field
      input = new TextField();
      add(input);
    }
    public void addMessage(String message) {
      messages.addMessage(message);   
    }
    public void appendTo(JFrame frame) {
       frame.getContentPane().add(this);   
    }
}
```

And here is the messageList:

```
public class MessageList extends JPanel {
    public MessageList() {
      setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    }
    public void addMessage(String message) {
      JLabel lb = new JLabel();
      lb.setText(message);
      add(lb);        
      validate();
    }
    public void appendTo(JPanel frame) {
       frame.add(new JScrollPane(this));   
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, don't mix AWT components, such as `java.awt.TextField`, with Swing components.

Comment: Thanks for warning me, however now when I know what not to do, I'm curious what should I do instead. Is there a swing textfield?

Comment: Yes, there is. "JTextField"

Comment: Most of swing components name starts with "J" letter."JCombobox,JCalendar etc."

Comment: I've linked to a related tutorial below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [*How to Use BoxLayout: Specifying Component Sizes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#size), you can [override](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) the `getXxxSize()` methods in your chosen [`JTextComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) subclass.

Comment: Also, most elements have `.setXxxSize` that is equal to overridding the method (but can, of course only set value to constant, while the method override can allow for more complex behavoir).

Comment: For several reasons, you may prefer to [override](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: I've read that already when I was googling for the answer. I really thought it applies to overriding as well. But if you know a good description of difference between the two approaches, that would be useful.

Comment: In this context, I see overriding as defensive. An alternative would be to use `BorderLayout.SOUTH` for the text area and nest the scrolling list in `CENTER`.